# Two equal XML with differences when reading the file on Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, parsing

I have to parse XML files coming from two different software. One of the files failed on the parsing process. So I started debugging the problem and I come to the point where I copied the "good file" content and paste it to the "bad file". But the error persisted! I also paste the "bad file" content into the good one, and everything worked!

I think that this has to do with some encoding problem.

If an XML file has no encoding declared, is there some metadata that I could be missing?

The output when I read the file on ruby

`File.read(Rails.root.join('bad-file.xml'))`

```
\xFF\xFE<\u0000f\u0000i\u0000l\u0000e\u0000>\u0000\r\u0000<\u0000A\u0000L\u0000L\u0000_\u0000I\u0000N\u0000S\u0000T\u0000A\u0000N\u0000C\u0000E\u0000S\u0000>\u0000\r\u0000\r\u0000<\u0000i\u0000n\u0000s\u0000t\u0000a\u0000n\u0000c\u0000e\u0000>\u0000\r\u0000<\u0000I\u0000D\u0000>\u00009\u00005\u00003\u0000<\u0000/\u0000I\u0000D\u0000>\u0000\r\u0000<\u0000s\u0000t\u0000a\u0000r\u0000t\u0000>\u00005\u00000\u00005\u00009\u0000.\u00002\u00006\u00002\u00002\u00000\u00001....
```

`File.read(Rails.root.join('good-file.xml'))`

```
<file>\r\n<ALL_INSTANCES>\r\n\r\n<instance>\r\n<ID>953</ID>\r\n<start>5059.2622016567</start>\r\n<end>5060.2622016567</end>\r\n<code>timer-1sec</code>\r\n<label>\r\n<group>result</group>\r\n<text>Dabang Eindringen SK</text>\r\n</label>\r\n</instance>\r\n</ALL_INSTANCES>\r\n\r\n<ROWS>\r\n<row>\r\n<code>timer-1sec</code>\r\n<R>0</R>\r\n<G>0</G>\r\n<B>0</B>\r\n</row>\r\n</ROWS>\r\n</file>
```

Comment: could be wrong but sounds like encoding issues.

Comment: yes, I think there is some problem with encoding too. But I thought that the encoding was declared on the XML headers. I don't really know what happens if there are no headers. Where's the encoding declared. Are there some metadata, how can I access the encoding info?

Comment: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/IO.html#method-c-read   you can specify the encoding as argument on how the file should be treated by Ruby. Look at http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Encoding.html for the various options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those first 2 bytes `\xFF\xFE` are a unicode byte order mark - they signify that the rest of the data is UTF16, in  little endian order

If you do

```
File.read(path, mode: 'r:UTF-16LE')
```

Then the external encoding for the file will be set to that. The data is transcoded to the default internal encoding before being returned. You can force that to utf-8 by doing

```
File.read(path, mode: 'r:UTF-16LE:UTF-8')
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you know how can I know the byte order before hand. Where is it specified? If I have two xml with the same content, where is the encoding and byte order determined?

Comment: Those first two bytes at the start of the file tell you this. They're not mandatory though. If they're not there you have to guess (e.g. using charlock_holmes)

Comment: Using both of those options I get "no implicit conversion of String into Integer" I'm going to try charlock_holmes

Comment: @limoragni sorry, was confusing File.open & File.read in my head (which needs the arguments in a different format)

Comment: Yes, I realized that after trying a couple of times. Thanks. This solved the problem with reading the file with UTF16 encoding, but if I use it on the other file I get Chinese characters! But it makes sense, is reading the file like if it where UTF16 encoded. Now I have to understand how can I check the encoding and propperly convert it to UTF-8. By the way I think the other file has Latin1 encoding. But I'm new to all this encoding problems! If you have some ideas that would like to add to your answer it would be great! Thanks!